# Need MYSQL Query for these table

Tags: mysql

Student Table

[image]

History Table

[image]

I want to display like this

```
id Name title1 total1 get1 year1 title2 total2 year2 title3 total3    get3 year3 
1 Usman Hayat Matric 850 600 2001 Inter 1100 900 2003 NULL NULL NULL NULL 
2 Hamid Khan  Matric 850 500 2002 Inter 1100 789 2004    BA 800 400 2006
```

Comment: Don't use images put your table schema and also put what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pivot for getting the requested result you can see further details on pivot here

[MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Go thorough this if still not able to write the query comment below will write query.